# PostMessage send ctrl + key in background

Tags: vb.net, background, key, postmessage, ctrl

I have this code but I don't know why it doesn't work, can anyone help me? I need to send ctrl + f to another application in the background

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form2

    Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Private Const WM_CHAR = &H102
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105
    Private Const VK_SHIFT = &H10
    Private Const VK_CONTROL = &H11
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = &H1
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = &H0
    Private Const VK_F = &H46
    Private Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Public Declare Function MapVirtualKey Lib "user32" Alias "MapVirtualKeyA" (ByVal wCode As Integer, ByVal wMapType As Integer) As Byte


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim hPadre As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hPadre, "Notepad", "Sin título: Bloc de notas")
        Dim hCarpetas As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hPadre, hCarpetas, "Edit", vbNullString)


        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0)
        PostMessage(hPadre, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F, 0)
        keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this example, but it doesn't work :(

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1

```
Private Const VK_CONTROL As Integer = 17
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2
Private Const INPUT_MOUSE As Integer = 0
Private Const INPUT_KEYBOARD As Integer = 1
Private Const INPUT_HARDWARE As Integer = 2
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H100 

Private Structure MOUSEINPUT
    Public dx As Integer
    Public dy As Integer
    Public mouseData As Integer
    Public dwFlags As Integer
    Public time As Integer
    Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Structure KEYBDINPUT
    Public wVk As Integer
    Public wScan As Integer
    Public dwFlags As Integer
    Public time As Integer
    Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Structure HARDWAREINPUT
    Public uMsg As Integer
    Public wParamL As Integer
    Public wParamH As Integer
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
Private Structure INPUT
    <FieldOffset(0)>
    Public type As Integer
    <FieldOffset(4)>
    Public mi As MOUSEINPUT
    <FieldOffset(4)>
    Public ki As KEYBDINPUT
    <FieldOffset(4)>
    Public hi As HARDWAREINPUT
End Structure

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function ' Dany

Private Declare Function SendInput Lib "user32" (ByVal nInputs As Integer, ByVal pInputs() As INPUT, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Integer

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal wMsg As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr 


Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Integer, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As IntPtr, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr) 


Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()
    Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
        ' Allows UI to remain responsive
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    sw.Stop()

End Sub
Private Sub SendKey(ByVal bKey As Integer)
    Dim GInput(0) As INPUT

    ' press the key
    GInput(0).type = INPUT_KEYBOARD
    GInput(0).ki.wVk = bKey
    GInput(0).ki.dwFlags = 0
    SendInput(2, GInput, Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(INPUT)))
End Sub

Sub Press_Control()
    wait(2000)
    Dim b As Integer
    b = VK_CONTROL
    SendKey(b)
End Sub




Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hPadre As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, hPadre, "Notepad", "Sin título: Bloc de notas")
    Dim hCarpetas As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(hPadre, hCarpetas, "Edit", vbNullString)

    Press_Control()
    SendMessage(hPadre, WM_KEYDOWN, 70, 0)
    wait(1000)
    keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)

End Sub
```